Number of pairs of indistinguisable particles
On pg. 18 of Quantum Many-Particle Systems, by Negele and Orland, the authors introduce the following operator which "counts the number of pairs of particles in the states $\vert\alpha\rangle$ and $\vert\beta\rangle$ [in the $n$-particle state $\vert\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n\rangle$]"
$$
\hat{P}_{\alpha\beta}=\hat{n}_\alpha\hat{n}_\beta-\delta_{\alpha\beta}\hat{n}_\alpha
$$
That is, if $\alpha\ne\beta$, the number of pairs is $n_\alpha n_\beta$, while if $\alpha=\beta$, the number of pairs is $n_\alpha\left(n_\alpha-1\right)$. I tried applying $\hat{P}_{\alpha\beta}$ to the bosonic state $\vert\alpha,\alpha,\alpha,\beta\rangle$ as an exercise. I found:
$$
\begin{align}
P_{\alpha\alpha}&=6\\
P_{\alpha\beta}&=3\\
P_{\beta\beta}&=0
\end{align}
$$
I see that the three pairs of $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ arise from pairing $\beta$ with the three occurrences of $\alpha$, while the six pairs of $\{\alpha,\alpha\}$ arise from the $3!$ ways of grouping three occurrences of $\alpha$ into pairs. My question is: why are $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\beta,\alpha)$ indistinct pairs according to $\hat{P}_{\alpha\beta}$, while every one of the six $(\alpha,\alpha)$ pairings are distinct? Why are there not just three pairs of $(\alpha,\alpha)$ - the $\alpha$ in the second slot of $\vert\alpha,\alpha,\alpha,\beta\rangle$ coupled with the $\alpha$ in the third slot, the second slot with the fourth slot, and the third slot with the fourth slot? More generally, what is the reasoning behind the statement

If $\alpha\ne\beta$, the number of pairs is $n_\alpha n_\beta$, while if $\alpha=\beta$, the number of pairs is $n_\alpha\left(n_\alpha-1\right)$?



Number of pairs of indistinguishable particles

I don't think the particles are indistinguishable. I think the particle pair is created by choosing one of $n$ distinguishable particles, then choosing one of the remaining $n-1$ particles. The particles are distinguishable and the order of particles within a pair matters too.
In your four particle $| \alpha, \alpha, \alpha, \beta\rangle$ example there are $12$ possible pairs, of which $6$ have states $(\alpha, \beta)$, $3$ have states $(\alpha, \beta)$ and $3$ have states $(\beta, \alpha)$.

This makes much more sense. Thank you!
